# Resource recommendations for Frobenius inner product and orthogonal matrices

Tags: inner-products, online-resources

I am trying to use the Frobenius inner product for some work. Are there any resources that somewhat comprehensively discuss this?

From what I can find through simple google searching, many resources don't go past a simple definition as

$$
\begin{align}
\langle A,B\rangle=\mathrm{tr}(AB^\intercal)\,.
\end{align}
$$